# Angular build doesn't find @types for some modules

Tags: angular, typescript, build, angular-cli

I have a strange problem.
The structure is the following:

- My own libraries outside of the app directory
- The main app, where the libraries are included via tsconfig.json and path included.

When I use "ng serve" everything works fine, doing a production build, the build fails with two main errors:

```
Error: ../../../../xy/advweb/dist/advweb/core/lib/validators/lessThanDate.validator.d.ts:2:26 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'luxon'. 'C:/_Projects/_Git/yy/Source/src/web/node_modules/luxon/build/node/luxon.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/luxon` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'luxon';`

2 import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
                           ~~~~~~~


Error: ../../../../xy/advweb/dist/advweb/leaflet/lib/components/map/map.component.d.ts:2:39 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'leaflet'. 'C:/_Projects/_Git/yy/Source/src/web/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  If the 'leaflet' package actually exposes this module, consider sending a pull request to amend 'https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/leaflet'

2 import { TileLayerOptions, Map } from 'leaflet';
```

**The types are installed in the app**. When "node_modules" is present in the library project, the build works. So it seems that the build is looking for the @types in the library structure and not in the app. @types redirecting via tsconfig.json doesn't help.
Why?
tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "traceResolution": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "module": "ES2022",
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": [
            "ES2022",
            "DOM"
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@angular/*": [
                "./node_modules/@angular/*"
            ],
            "luxon": [
                "./node_modules/luxon"
            ],
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/*"
            ],
            "@advweb/core": [
                "../../../../xy/advweb/dist/advweb/core"
            ],
            "@advweb/kendo2": [
                "../../../../xy/advweb/dist/advweb/kendo2"
            ],
            "@advweb/leaflet": [
                "../../../../xy/advweb/dist/advweb/leaflet"
            ]
        }
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
    {
          "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
          "compilerOptions": {
            "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
            "types": []
          },
          "files": [
            "src/main.ts"
          ],
          "include": [
            "src/**/*.d.ts"
          ]
    }
```

I made a smaller sample project, with the same structure, there the build works. I'm using more or less the same angular.json and tsconfig.json in the app and in the sample. But the result is different.

Comment: Can you please add your tsconfig.app.json?

Answer (score 1):

`types` is used to specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file.

When you leave the array empty, this excludes types.

If you remove the `types` definition from `tsconfig.app.json` it should allow all types that are in the `typeRoots` which if I'm not mistaken, defaults to `node_modules/@types`

Comment: I tried that, including in the lib and in the app both types ("luxon" and "leaflet") and also completely removing `types`. But still the same error.  Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...

Comment: Like here https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#installable-typings-files

Comment: Does your library declare `peerDependencies` of `luxon` and `leaflet`? and does your main project have those in the `dependencies`?

Comment: Yes and yes. I added `"traceResolution": true` to tsconfig to see what happens. `luxon` I also use directly in the main project, there the types are resolved correctly. But for the libraries, it seems to resolve it following the library path upwards (where no `node_modules` are). Seems compiler doesn't care in this case for main project paths redirect in the `tsconfig.json`. I would like to post it on Angular GitHub, but without a failing sample project, no chances.

Comment: BTW: The module `luxon` is resolved correctly from the library to the main project, only the @types are failing. And `leaflet` and `luxon` are the only CommonJs modules without included type definitions I use.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, luxon includes its own definitions, so you probably don't need @types/luxon at all. I'm not not exactly sure what's going on with your project, but the use of `paths` in your tsconfig is a bit confusing for me. I typically only provide path statements for directories in the project code itself, not back to node_modules or to directories outside of the baseUrl

Comment: Thanks for your help. As I known luxon hasn't his own types, at least there is no d.ts file included. And if you don't wan't to pusblish your libraries always to NPM, this (`paths`) is the only way to include external local libraries.

Comment: I thought that's what `typeRoots` was for. To the best of my knowledge, `paths` allows you to do shortcuts for imports relative to the `baseUrl`. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Comment: `paths` I used to resolve imports like `@advweb/core`. I looked into `typeRoots`, but didn't see a way there. Anyway, after your hint, better not to use `paths`, I found another way, the `NPM` way. I'm installing my libraries now via `NPM i <relative library path>`. Now all files a under the main project, my libraries are linked. And it seems to work. Still doing some more testing.

Comment: Super! Glad you found a solution